# How to combine 2 alias commands in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

For combining 2 alias commands. below are the commands to do it.

`command1` output is multiple line which begins with job id;
**53468837**  4.00005  abcdefg    myuserid  r  2022-12-21T17:09:29.695  machine@server1  144

**53468840**  4.00005  hiaafd    myuserid  r  2022-12-21T17:09:29.695  machine@server2  144

`command2` expects one of above Job id (first column) as input but should be entered manually.

how can i combine both commands together in one line (inside alias file) something like alias test=command1; command2 53468837 or 53468840

Note:
if this is tricky, one can suggest a small bash script as well. even assigning line number to each line, so that selection will be based on line number instead job id.
[Output of `command1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HduE.png)

Comment: Create a bash function instead of an alias

Comment: Sometime before 1996, the line "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions" was added to the Bash documentation.  Why anyone uses aliases at all is baffling to me.

Comment: @Nayak, clarify "not working". When you use `command1` and `command2` stand-ins, nobody but you can test your code. We need a [mre] others can use to _see the problem ourselves_; if nobody can test their answers, nobody can write an answer they actually trust.

Comment: @Nayad, ...and whitespace matters in function syntax. It should be `yourfunction() { command1; command2 '!=1'; }` -- note the space after the `{`, note the semicolon (or newline, or some other kind of command separator) and space before the `}`. Don't use the name `test` -- that's a shell builtin command and should never be overridden. And don't use the `function` keyword -- see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: If command2 expects command1's output on stdin, maybe that needs to be `yourfunction() { command1 | command2 '!=1'; }`, but again, we need a [mre] we can test ourselves to be able to build answers we can trust.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, see i have edited my question, and added a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what *exactly* OP's `command1` generates so the following may need some tweaking ...

As others have commented, and in light of the (some level of) complexity of the requirement, functions may be preferred over aliases.

One idea using functions:

```
command1 () { echo 12345 45687 98765; }
command2 () { command1 | awk -v n="$1" '{print $n}'; }
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ command2 1                  # print 1st arg from command1 output
12345

$ command2 2                  # print 2nd arg from command1 output
45687

$ command2 3                  # print 3rd arg from command1 output
98765
```

---

Taking it a bit further and assuming OP needs the ability to dynamically define the first 'command' during the call to the second 'command':

```
command1 () { echo C1.12345 C1.45687 C1.98765; }
command2 () { echo C2.abcde C2.defgh C2.wxyz; }
command3 () { echo C3.Hello C3.world; }

commandX () { "$1" | awk -v n="$2" '{print $n}'; }   # run command '$1' and pipe results to 'awk' to print the '$2'th field
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ commandX command1 3
C1.98765

$ commandX command2 2
C2.defgh

$ commandX command3 1
C3.Hello
```

---

**NOTES:**

- again, it's not clear (to me) what OP's `command1` generates so it's likely the function code may need to change
- OP will want to add some logic to validate the input to `command2` (eg, just one arg? must be a positive integer? what to do if larger than the number of fields generated by `command1`?, etc)
- in both sets of code I've used `awk` for demonstration purposes; there's nothing to keep OP from replacing the `awk` code with something else that performs the desired operation on the output from the 1st 'command'
- in the 2nd set of code I've used other functions (`command[123]`) for demonstration purposes; there's nothing to keep OP from defining `commandX` to take any command (function, script, binary) as its 1st argument ... even going so far as to allow for command line args to be fed to the 1st argument ... but now we're getting a bit more complicated without more details of OP's *actual* requirement
- if this doesn't address OP's requirement then OP should consider updating the question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)